# How to change style of WebAuthenticationBroker generated dialog?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have just tried to use `WebAuthenticationBroker` for connection to Google but I don't like the visual representation of the system generated dialog. Is it possible to change it somehow?

For example this is a screenshot of English version:

[image: English version]

Those white rectangles are really ugly but this have even worse impact when changing language:

[image: Czech version]

The bottom status line flows under the drop down for changing language.

I would like to expand the container used for the web page rendering to the full width of the dialog (C# and XAML). How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot style the shell of the dialog.  This is to provide confidence to the Windows user and a consistent experience.  Most auth providers have a "mobile" view that works better in their auth URIs.  For instance, Facebook's basic OAuth starting point is horrible for this dialog, but using the Mobile one it formats very well.  As to your comment of how the text flows...this looks not like a WebAuthBroker dialog issue but rather an IE10 rendering issue and Google would need to examine their HTML being used to understand why.

Comment: The mobile touch view for facebook has issues if you ask for extended permissions.  The other options create side and vertical scrolling in the dialog.  We at minimum need the ability to change the iframe width otherwise this is a useless solution.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this. This will help:

http://www.naweed.info/Links/Post/9