# How to scroll in WebAuthenticationBroker?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, linkedin-api

I am creating a Windows 8 app. I want user to login with LinkedIn. I am using `WebAuthenticationBroker` for that. But it's not showing the authorization dialog correctly. The "Allow Access" button remains hide and due to unavailability of scroll-bar one can't scroll.

[image]

I also tried [Windows 8/RT WebAuthenticationBroker view issue - Alternative](http://www.naweed.info/Links/Post/9). It uses `WebView` and provides better view, but it's useless for me because it's not returning me the authorization code i.e. OAuth response.

According to [Tim Heuer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12030037/1230188) it's not possible to customize the `WebAuthenticationBroker` and I suspect there's issues in LinkedIn dialog itself.

Anyone has idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: If you are willing to make the app only for windows 8.1 you should be able to make the WebView alternative work by replacing LoadComplete event by the Navigating event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows 8/RT WebAuthenticationBroker view issue - Alternative](http://www.naweed.info/Links/Post/9) worked for me. I had issues in callback URL.